# Can I use a php file to enter variables and echo them in the html page?

Tags: php, html

I am coding a one page lander for someone that know's little about code.
So I was thinking of making it really user friendly on the parts that require customization, things like the `<title></title>` and some headlines on the website, as well as some URLs in **another** php file.

My idea is to make a main file, lets call it `main_file.php` to make it easy.

in `main_file.php` I want to have: (for example)

```
$title = "web page title here";
$headline = "headline here"
$URL1 = "http://a custom url here.com";
etc
```

And have the above `echo`'d in the right files.

The goal of this being that the user I am coding this for, will only have to edit one clear file, with instructions etc as needed.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Include the file and output the variables.

Comment: how do I output `$title = "title"` in `<title></title>` for example?

Comment: `echo '<title>' . $title . '</title>';` You may also want to convert the user's input if they're likely to use `<`, `>`; or use a WYSIWYG.

Comment: would `<title><?php echo $titlle ?></title>` work? (on the html page)

Comment: Yes, give it a try. See what works, what doesn't. Come back with questions/errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do that.

Your configuration file is `main_file.php` right?

```
your-application/main_file.php
```

Then, you have a master layout/template for example:

```
your-application/index.php
```

In this layout you can include the main file in the first line:

```
<?php include ('main_file.php'); ?>
<!-- the rest of the code below -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $page_tile ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $some_text_variable ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Done!

All variables declared in `main_file.php` are now available in `index.php`.

---

- The template/layout file **must be a php file**, but you can put your html inside, understood?